# R: Passing filenames to argument

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Currently working on Bioinformatics diagrams from lists of species, line separated. I have five genes covered and I am generating overlap of matched species (i.e. ribosomal gene coverage comparisons).

```
RScript VennGenSpec.R Gene1Spec Gene2Spec Gene3Spec Gene4Spec Gene5Spec Output
```

Right now I am generating five set venn diagrams in a pdf format, but wanted to generalize the function to allow different number of species sets. How can I generate some loops that read a variable amount of lists? (E.g. generate 4 set venns, 7 set, depending on number of inputs.)

```
# install venn package
# install.packages("venn")
library("venn")
# load taxa lists
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

fia<-args[1]
fib<-args[2]
fic<-args[3]
fid<-args[4]
fie<-args[5]
out<-args[6]

##get lists
a<-read.table(fia)
b<-read.table(fib)
c<-read.table(fic)
d<-read.table(fid)
e<-read.table(fie)

#set pdf output
pdf(paste(out,"pdf",sep="."))

#plot venn
venn(list(a[,1],b[,1],c[,1],d[,1],e[,1]), snames = c("G1","G2","G3","G4","G5"), counts = NULL, ellipse = FALSE, zcolor = "style", size = 15, cexsn = 1, borders = TRUE)
```

Sample Venn Output: [VennExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBCng.png)

```
for (i in (1:(arguments-1)) ) {
    fi[i] <-args[i]
}
else
output <-args[last]

for (i in (arguments -1) ) {
    ta[i] <-read.table(fi[i])
}

sys.call
match.call
```

Also wanted to pass the names of the species list into the diagram itself [where snames is]. I have the mockup names as G1 gene 1 etc... above

```
batch_args <- read.table(args[1], sep=",")

for
```

I apologize for the longer post.

Answer (score 1):

Without data to test the code, it's impossible to know whether the following does what you want but it is, at least apparently, equivalent to your code and much simpler.

It reads all data.frames in one go and keeps them in a list, `fi`. Then, extracts the first column of each df and passes the resulting list of vectors to `venn`.

```
library("venn")

# load taxa lists
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

n <- length(args)
fi <- args[-n]
out <- args[n]

##get lists
a <- lapply(fi, read.table)
##get first column of each data.frame
a1 <- lapply(a, `[[`, 1)

#set pdf output
pdf(paste(out, "pdf", sep = "."))

#plot venn
venn(a1, 
     snames = paste0("G", seq_along(a1)), 
     counts = NULL, ellipse = FALSE, 
     zcolor = "style", size = 15, 
     cexsn = 1, borders = TRUE
     )
dev.off()
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for the simplification! It did appear to run with a number of cases. I'll definitely be able to use lapply in this manner on another script. [To be fully honest this is my first foray at some stuff in R, and I'm doing this as a weekend/learning experience.]

Comment: Would it be possible to pass over the file names to the data frame and use it in for labeling the set lists? All the input files are labeled with the gene of interest after being selected from a larger dataset. 

##get lists
a <- lapply(fi, function(n) {
 data <- read.table(n)
 data$fileName <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(n))
 data
})
##get first column of each data.frame
a1 <- lapply(a, `[[`, 1)
##get second column 
a2 <- lapply(a, `[[`, 2)

#plot venn
venn(a1, 
     snames = paste0(a2),

Not the right matching for the set names.